Documentation's Quickstart python code for google-gemini stalls
import google.generativeai as genai
genai.configure(api_key="XXXXXREDACTEDXXXXX")
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash')
response = model.generate_content("Give me python code to sort a list")
print(response.text)

The above code is from https://github.com/google-gemini/cookbook/blob/main/quickstarts/Prompting.ipynb but i removed the google collab components of it as i am running it locally on my laptop. The program freezes and gives no output, just a forever blinking cursor. It is supposed to reply to given prompt
I expected it to run properly as shown in documentation but it doesnt
gives this error after 10 mins
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Timeout of 600.0s exceeded, last exception: 503 DNS resolution failed for generativelanguage.googleapis.com:443: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=SRV name=_grpclb._tcp.generativelanguage.googleapis.com: DNS query cancelled
